# Rails nested route with shallow and empty path - can't edit entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is the first time I've used nested routes with shallow and I'm struggling to get my edit action to work (I'm also learning more Rails stuff).

So a group can have multiple group actions assigned to it, so my route is set up as

```
resources :groups do
  get 'actions', to: 'group_actions#index', as: :actions
  get 'actions/new', to: 'group_actions#new', as: :new_action
  post 'actions', to: 'group_actions#create'
  resources :group_actions, path: '', as: :actions, except: [:index, :new, :create], shallow: true, shallow_path: 'actions/:group_id'
end
```

The reason for the empty path is so we can easily manage conflicting group action names by appending the group_id before it, so an action URL would be...

`/actions/17/action-name`

for example. This of course causes an issue with the index/new actions within a nested route so I manually set those routes as above. This all seems to work fine, actions can be created, deleted, viewed etc but I can't edit them.

This gives me the following routes...

```
group_actions    GET   /groups/:group_id/actions(.:format) group_actions#index
group_new_action GET   /groups/:group_id/actions/new(.:format)      
group_actions#new           
             POST  /groups/:group_id/actions(.:format) group_actions#create
edit_action      GET   /actions/:group_id/:id/edit(.:format) group_actions#edit
action           GET   /actions/:group_id/:id(.:format) group_actions#show
             PATCH /actions/:group_id/:id(.:format)group_actions#update
             PUT   /actions/:group_id/:id(.:format) group_actions#update
             DELETE /actions/:group_id/:id(.:format)
```

My GroupAction controller is as so...

```
class GroupActionsController < ApplicationController

before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show, :index]
before_action :set_group, only: [:index, :show, :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
  @group_actions = GroupAction.all

end

def show
  @group_action = GroupAction.find(params[:id])
end

def new
  @group_action = @group.group_actions.build
end

def edit
  @group_action = GroupAction.find(params[:id])
end

def create
  @group_action = GroupAction.new(group_action_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @group_action.save
      format.html { redirect_to group_actions_path(@group.slug), notice: 'Group Action successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, group: @group }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @group.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @group_action.update(group_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @group_action, notice: 'Action was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @group_action }
      GaTrack.event(:group, :updated, "#{@group_action.name}")
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @group_action.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def destroy
  @group_action = GroupAction.find(params[:id])
  @group_action.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to group_actions_path(@group.slug), notice: 'Action was successfully deleted.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

private

  def set_group
    @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
  end

  def group_action_params
    params.require(:group_action).permit(:name, :description, :location, :start_date, :end_date, :how_to_participate, :intro_email, :update_email, :thank_you_email, :action_link, :is_public, :group_id)
  end
end
```

I'm then trying to share my new/edit forms and this is where I'm not understanding the issue.

new.html.erb

```
<h1>New Group Action</h1>

<%= render 'form', group_action: @group_action %>
```

edit.html.erb

```
<h1>New Group Action</h1>

<%= render 'form', group_action: @group_action %>
```

When trying to edit an action I get the following error...

```
undefined method `group_action_path' for #<#  
<Class:0x007f855e30b2c8>:0x007f855e3163a8>
Did you mean?  group_actions_path
               group_locations_path
               group_new_action_path
               group_actions_url
```

Comment: when you are getting this error?

Comment: On trying to edit

Comment: You don't specify where you're receving that error. Add the whole error message.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up wrapping the form in separate `form_for`so I could use the url option for editing, which works for now.

```
<%= form_for(@group_action, url: action_path) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'form', f: f %>
<% end %>
```